What are the negatives of building a wall with built in cabinets?
We are going to be borrowing space from a bedroom to add a hallway between two rooms. Two bedrooms share a wall and we want a hallway through this area.
The existing wall between the rooms will be one side of the hallway and I was thinking of trying get someone to build custom cabinets in between the new divider wall studs to create the second “wall” of the hallway separating it from the existing bedroom. I would need the cabinet openings between studs to be 36” wide instead the of the usual 16” but since this is not a load bearing wall I don’t see why that should be a problem. My walls are about 6” thick so I was thinking this would be a great way to utilize space if we built in 2ft deep cabinets. We would only be stealing a foot and a half of additional space from the room to make a storage closet.
I can’t find any articles about doing this so I’m wondering if there is something I’m missing other than that noise may be an issue in the bedroom. It’s a guest room that is never used so that’s not an issue. I could really use the storage.

Extra storage is always a pro.  If you have the floor space and sure the walls being moved are not load bearing, then it should work.  Not sure about adding a hallway, unless a walk-in closet is the idea.  Pictures/diagram will help.

Better of just building a regular wall (normally only 4 1/2" thick) and then buying a shelving system or building a built-in. This would be better if you change your mind later or are selling.

are you talking about walk-in closet, no a hallway

Common bathroom cabinets demonstrate that it can certainly be done. Of course, you have to either limit the cabinet width to fit between studs, or properly frame out the space the same way you would a door or window so the weight above is still carried properly.
The biggest downside, outside of the fact that the next person to buy the house may not like your solution, is that you may be removing insulation if it's an outside wall, or sound isolation if it's an inside wall. You would also be making it more difficult to route cables and pipes in the future, if that ever becomes necessary, since they might have to dodge around this rather than going straight up the wall.
Personally, my attitude would be that if they don't like it, it isn't hard to reverse; just take out anything that extends into the room and apply new wallboard. And I plan to live in my house for the next several decades, so selling it really isn't on my radar; I would rather adapt it to my needs and not worry about whether the adaptation appeals to anyone else or not. However, the insulation/isolation issue bothers me. I think I would settle for using the space inside the house, rather than trying to squeeze a few extra square feet out of the framing.

While 16 or 24 inch oc is standard stud spacing, studs in the centre of a 4x8 drywall sheet does not need to meet that spacing(within reason) on a non load bearing wall.  Can see a few 5 inch by 3ft cabinets might be handy.  Rolled up sheets/blankets/towels will fit in.

There is nothing wrong with this, but you do need to make sure you really have the space to do it right. Hallways should be, according to code, 3 feet wide.
You might think (and might be right, I don't know) that you can get away with a narrower hallway if this is a hallway that isn't strictly needed - after all, it didn't even exist until now. However, 3 feet is really important to have safe access, and it is even more important with these cabinets. Imagine someone opening up a cabinet and moving stuff around and someone else needs to squeeze by - 3 feet really becomes important.
That means you are really taking 5-1/2 feet out of one of the rooms - 3 feet for a hallway, 2 feet for a cabinet and 6" for a wall. Yes, you read that right - you still need a real wall between the cabinet and the bedroom. You might be able to get away with a bit less if the cabinet is less than 2 feet deep or if the wall is not as thick. You can make a sturdy wall 4-1/2" thick - 3-1/2" for a 2x4 + 1/2" drywall on each side.
On the cabinet side you may want to use 1/2" plywood instead of drywall. Cheaper grades won't finish as nicely as drywall, but you can just slap some white paint on it and be done - nobody will care inside the cabinet. It has the really nice advantage of strength, particularly if you want to add shelves, hooks, etc.

It sounds like you want to build walk-in closet.
For that you do not need second wall with studs.
You need a self supporting cabinet made out of plywood
It only needs a cabinet structure that will stand by it self, not mounted between the studs.
You still need 36" spacing from the existing wall and then build a 24" deep cabinet with its back-wall facing the bedroom. You only need to anchor it to the ceiling and the floor with some screws
